# Add a js library only at a section of the HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a logo slider where a `js library` is required.
At the head of my HTML code I have another `js library` which is overwritten by the library required for the slider.
My question is, can I use the slider's `js library` only at a specific part of my HTML code?

Comment: No you cannot. What you mean by overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The execution environment for JS is "the page".

The closest you could come would be to use an `iframe` to load a different page to sandbox it in.

---

You should fix the incompatibility between the two libraries instead.